# ID properties on Domain objects in DDD

Tags: programming-practices, domain-driven-design, clean-code, domain-model

In my domain I have an `Account` object.

e.g.

```csharp
class Account
{
    public string Number;
    public string SortCode;
}
```

Within the context of DDD, should this account object have an `ID` property? The `ID` would be a primary key, basically a database artefact.

Comment: What do you mean by "ID property"?

Comment: @Euphoric The `ID` would be a primary key, basically a database artefact.

Comment: surely 'Number' is unique?

Comment: @Ewan no, it's definately not.

Comment: How would one identify an account, if not by its identifier? Suppose I want to change the sortcode of an account. _Which account?_

Comment: _"The ID would be a primary key, basically a database artefact."_ You've conflated two things here, because that is not a given. These are two separate things to consider: (a) Should the account have a unique identifier and (b) should I reuse my database's unique account identifier as the value for my domain's unique account identifier?

Comment: If you change the sort code of an account then it would be a different account.

Comment: @BanksySan: So then SortCode _is_ a unique identifier of an account?

Answer (score 11):

It depends. If your `Account` class shall be mapped to a relational database, then its not just a good idea, but proven practice, to use technical IDs for every table as PKs (and FKs, referencing those PKs). To my experience, separating the technical PK of all tables from the "domain keys" (like the "bank account number") works very well and helps you to avoid all kind of technical issues. I typically name those PKs not just `ID`, but `<class-Name>Id`, so in your case `AccountID`.

If your class above will just be used as an input to a code generator which will generate the "real" code of your implementation language as well as your `CREATE TABLE` statements, some CRUD code etc., you probably don't need to add the ID attribute in the class code directly. If you are going to use an ORM, it depends on the ORM if it can add ID attributes as PKs automatically, or if it expects you to add those IDs manually.

In a DDD context, it may probably be helpful to hide those technical details when discussing the model with your domain experts, but show them when you change your viewpoint to the implementation of the model. If your tool set allows to display the model in those different levels of abstraction, make use of it. But if the tool set does not allow it, add the ID attributes and tell your domain experts that those are just "technical attributes".

Comment: Should my Domain be unaware of my database?

Comment: @BanksySan: Your "Domain", your "Domain experts" or your "Domain model"? Ideally, your toolset allows to show different presentations of your domain model. For example, an UML model where the IDs are not visible (for discussion with your experts), and a representation in code where they are visible. And of course, your domain experts should be aware of your database, but do they don't have to know every technical detail of your database implementation.

Comment: Hiding the database ID is one way of [Persistence Ignorance or Polyglot Persistence](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html) It means that the business logic itself doesn't know about persistence. Most of the DDD implementations I see do expose the ID, which is IMHO to be avoided if possible. This is why e.g. I [added another automated translation layer over our ORM](http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITLE_561), to convert DDD Aggregates and ORM records.

Comment: This answer does not seem written "within the context of DDD". DDD goes beyond "discussing the model with your domain experts". When _implementing_ the domain layer as a _domain model_ (as opposed to your description which seems more in line with an _active record_), I believe there is a good point to be made not to include the ID in the implementation. [Arnoud's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/299668/15464) points this out nicely.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: "context of DDD" is a very vague term. On some lower layer of abstraction, developers who implement the domain model in code will need access to the ID, and the database will need it for allowing foreign key constraints. I don't see this lower levels excluded by speaking of "within the context of DDD" - for me this reads more like "in a project where the DDD methodology is used".

Comment: That is true @DocBrown, but ideally that would be on the infrastructure layer (lower layer of abstraction as you put it), not the domain layer. Following a domain model implementation, the goal is to keep the domain model persistence ignorant. For example, consider this: would the ID of the same object remain the same in case the object moves from a local database to a distributed system, or it gets send from one database to another? Not to say that a 'domain model' is the way to go for all systems, but I believe this is implied by stating "within the context of DDD".

Comment: @StevenJeuris: well, only the OP can clarify if he meant "in the domain layer" when he wrote "within context of DDD" - my understanding when I wrote my answer was quite different, and I am not convinced that he meant the former. However, I have my experience from implementing a quite large business model in a multi team project with >500 tables using techniques very similar to DDD before that term was even invented, and the idea of "including a uniform surrogate ID to each table", even if it is not directly business related, turned out to be very benefical.

Comment: ... in modeling as well as in implementation. And we did exactly what I wrote above - we hided the ID field from the graphical class model, and from out domain experts, but let the ORM's code generator generate the fields. So my advice to the OP is, it makes sense to introduce such an ID, but depending on the tool set he uses, he should check at which level the ID will become visible and at which not.

Comment: @Doc Brown, I have asked a follow on question here and would be interested in your thoughts:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365570/how-to-generate-a-natural-key-for-a-domain-entity.  At the moment my entities have Guids even though my domain model is isolated from the ORM.

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time, the `ID` field you are talking about would be generated by the database, e.g. as a RDBMS sequence or a [NoSQL unique identifier](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/). It is therefore tied to the corresponding database backend used.

According to the [Persistence Ignorance / Polyglot Persistence principle](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html), you should better hide this `ID` from your domain aggregates as much as possible.

In practice, your domain Aggregates may already have an unique identifier. For instance, a serial number, a client code, a logon name, an account number, an invoice reference or an ISBN for a book.

If there is no such "natural" identifier in your model, it may be one role of the domain logic to *generate* such genuine identifiers, e.g. following a pattern defined by regulation, or human-friendly notions, following your company best practice (it is common to include the year and the month in invoice numbers, or an alphanumeric identifier of the department in charge of the process for instance).

Within the *Infrastructure Layer*, you would probably let an `ID` field appear, especially if you need to construct joined SQL queries among several RBDMS tables. Or, if you use an ORM, you may not persist directly the DDD aggregate objects as ORM objects, but use an "agnostic" translation layer. This is for instance [what our DDD framework proposes](http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITLE_561), by adding an automated translation layer between the DDD plain objects and the ORM objects, which have their own ID... some kind of "square ORM": on DDD mapper over an ORM mapper.

DDD is mainly about *isolation*: don't pollute your domain with database consideration! Naming an aggregate object field as `ID` does definitively smell: there is probably another naming, compatible with the *Ubiquitous Language* of your bounded context, which may be used instead of a plain `ID`.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that id is a database artefact. How do you know that account you are working with is correct? You know it's a correct account because it probably has a unique identifier. In your case the unique identifier is called "Id", so naturally you think it's a database artefact. Because of this I think that it's perfectly fine to have Id property in your domain model.

On a side note, I would NOT have a foreign key property in a domain model. For example, instead of having AddressId in the domain model, I would have an Address property and that would contain the address id.

Comment: In this instance (as it's a UK account) the account is identifiable by the combination of it's sort code and account number.  If it were international then it might be different properties or an IBAN.

Comment: Good point. Then there might not be a need for Id at all.

Comment: When a relational DB is used, not adding a technical Id will lead to the usage of domain keys as foreign keys. So in this case, every table referencing the `Account` table will store a duplicate of the "sort number" and the "account number". Now imagine what will happen if some domain requirements change (like local country bank account numbers to be replaced by IBAN, as its currently happening in Europe). Believe me, the usage of technical IDs leads to much more stable models, avoiding a lot of real-world problem which you otherwise have to deal with.

Comment: As @DocBrown points out: resist the temptation to piggy back on a domain property - they're always prone to change (no matter how sure you are). That said, I consider the ID, or unique key, part of the domain model.

Comment: Agreed with @DocBrown, using existing concepts to function as identifiers may prove to be unstable, therefore in many cases it is required to create a new ID concept, as part of the model.

Answer (score 0):

The question easer to answer from the end. You are trying to add primary key, since I would use following thought process

1. *Why we need PK?* - are we going to search in this table? Is it more than 3-10 records etc?  - If we can say yes, that means we have a need for clustered index (do not mix with PK, PK creates it as a side effect).

A **clustered index** is an index which defines the physical order in which table records are stored in a database.

2. *Do we really need PK or it is enough to have unique key?* - Unique also can be the baseline for clustered index. Let's imagine we can use unique
3. *How big index key would be?* - There might be multiple options but let's consider only 2: Your field **Number** is unique and can be from 1 to 50000. The uniqueness of record can be define only by combination of fields **SortOrder** and **Number**. While in 1st option I would most likely create PK on top of field Number, in second one I would introduce generic ID to simplify clustered index structure and size.

Now we can get back to DDD itself - *"In terms of object-oriented programming it means that the structure and language of software code (class names, class methods, class variables) should match the business domain. For example, if a software processes loan applications, it might have classes like LoanApplication and Customer, and methods such as AcceptOffer and Withdraw."*

ID logically is a result of function executed against the attributes that uniquely identify your record and produce integer as output, since it is a synthetic attribute of your domain model. It may be required to shorten object identification or not.

However worth to mention that applying different structure to different tables confuse developers (and that is major reason, why people use ID), practically you truly needed rarely. So it is also about balance in code and ability to maintain it.