# Is it normal for a Domain Model not to have an ID?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, entity

After reading the book; I understood the following:

1) Entities should implement equality and compare by ID.
2) Value Objects should implement equality and compare by all properties in the class.

I still believe that my understanding of point two is correct.  However, I am confused about point one because of the following:

1) This blogger talks about creating an entity base class, which all entities inherit from: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/08/domain-object-base-class/.  Therefore all entities implement equality by ID because the equality comparisons are defined in the base class.

2) Most of the entity classes here have IDs: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate.DomainModel/Northwind/Entities

3) This question seems to suggest having an ID attribute: [ID properties on Domain objects in DDD](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235254/id-properties-on-domain-objects-in-ddd)

4) This question points to a YouTube video (point one) where it is argued that entities should not have IDs.

Points 1-4 above seem to suggest either: 1) use a database ID; 2) use another ID that is not the database ID; 3) Use no ID.

I am trying to decide whether:

1) Have an entity superclass.

or
2) Have an ID (from database) in every entity.

or
3) Introduce an identifier (not database id) that identifies domain objects.

I am trying to completely isolate the domain model (I also have a data model).

Comment: Which one are you leaning towards and why?

Comment: The blog post you linked to in point 1 was mentioned on this site recently and was received with a healthy and appropriate amount of scepticism.  I believe the issue was specifically about his statement "you need to create the Id property in every single entity, which itself is a heavy violation of the DRY principle.".  I wouldn't get too hung up on anything he says.  Anyone can put up a blog and call themselves a craftsman.  On a separate note, please check out my artisanal beers blog.

Comment: @MetaFight, could you provide a link to your blog? Which option would you go with i.e. 1, 2 or 3.?

Comment: @Bernard, I am leaned towards having no ID at all.  My domain model is isolated so I don't believe it is needed.  However, I don't want to discover that I do actually need it at some point in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By definition, *entities* have an identity.

This fact, by itself, does not imply that you must have an `Id` property on your entity objects. If you never need to reference or compare the entity outside of your aggregate, there is not really a need for it.

Usually however, it makes sense for every entity to have an Id. Where does the Id come from? Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, I would prefer to have the application create the Id, not the database. You can use UUIDs (`Guid` in C#) or some custom `IdGenerator`. The fact that the database may use the `Id` value as a key is purely coincidental as far as your domain model is concerned.

This leaves the question of the `Entity` base class. There are a few reasons why you might not want to have one:

- `Entity` is not a domain concept, so having your domain objects depend on it is not ideal.

  You might argue that `Id` is not a domain concept, either. Practical reasons for introducing it aside, I would argue that identity *is* an implicit domain concern - otherwise you could just use value objects.
- The `Entity` will have very little functionality. Inheriting from it just to have an `Id` property, and possibly a very stable one-line (`this.Id == other.Id`) equality check seems like overkill.

That being said, I think it's very unlikely you'll run into problems due to the `Entity` base class. So if it helps you to focus on the domain logic (e.g. by not allowing you to forget to override `Equals`, in case this is how you intend to implement the equality check), by all means go for it.

Comment: How would the ID by generated? Guid.newid is used to generate the ID for the database in the Infrastructure layer.  However, it seems not right to pass this ID to the domain layer.

Comment: @w0051977 no, the DB has nothing to do with the Id conceptually - though it will likely use the Id. Whatever is creating your entities (constructor/factory) should usually create the Id. To the database, it's just a happy coincident that there is an Id field that might be used as a key.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you saying that the ID in the Infrastructure layer (Guid.NewID) would be different to the ID in the Domain Layer?

Comment: No the DB should use the entity's Id value, not create a second Id. But the database doesn't control the Id, it just uses it (as may other components of the system). Basically you move `Guid.NewId()` to your constructor/factory.

Comment: Thanks.  I think you are saying "tell don't ask".  That is how my infrastructure works i.e. the data object is created in memory with an ID and then persisted.  However, if the Domain Model is used, then should the ID be passed to the domain model?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. If you create a *new* entity, creating the Id should be part of the construction. If you load an *existing* entity from the DB, the Id must be provided by the DB, just like all the other values.

Comment: I am planning to have a separate data model and domain model as described here: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/04/05/having-the-domain-model-separate-from-the-persistence-model/.  Therefore I don't think an ID is needed in the domain model.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: "outside of your aggregate"? I believe an ID is needed inside the aggregate as well.  For example, if I wanted to map Customer.Orders from the domain model to the data model.

Comment: Sorry, can’t read right now. The Id is not just used to serve as database key. You also need it to reference & compare entities. The (mostly theoretical) corner case where your entity is never referenced outside the aggregate doesn’t apply, because your data model needs to reference everything. If your data model infrastructure forces you to create a data-model Id, then the domain model Id becomes just another value, like ‘First Name’.